# Why am I getting an "object expected" error in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

This code:

```
function foo(){
    var x = 5;
    var y = "8.8";
    var exp1 = typeof(2 * y);
    var exp2 = typeof(x + y);
    var exp3 = typeof(parsefloat(x + y));
    var exp4 = typeof(x + parsefloat(y));
    var exp5 = typeof(x + parseint(y));
    var exp6 = typeof(x-y);
    var exp7 = typeof(x*y);
    alert( exp1 + ", " + exp2 + ", " + exp3 + ", " + exp4 + ", " + exp5 + ", " + exp6 + ", " + exp7 + "." );
}
```

Gives me an "object expected" error on the line starting with `var exp3`, character 2.

**Edit:**

Not necessary, but *why* is it an error on character 2?

Comment: Try changing 'parsefloat' to 'parseFloat' and 'parseint' to 'parseInt'. Other than that, when I tried in IE9, this worked for me.

Comment: For testing you can use [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638132/how-to-save-the-javascript-errors-in-file/6638310#6638310)

Comment: IE javascript error messages make me wish it was strangled at birth. the text isn't that bad but the bogus line numbers get me every time :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. Use `parseFloat` and `parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

```
parsefloat(x + y)
```

should be

```
parseFloat(x + y) // capital F
```

and

```
parseint(y)
```

should be

```
parseInt(y) // capital I
```

Answer (score 1):

It's "parseFloat" and "parseInt".  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Change `parsefloat` and `parseint` to `parseFloat` and `parseInt` respectively.